# firefox, jQuery ajax calls firing twice and never triggering success or error functions

Tags: asp.net, jquery, firefox

I am developing with the .NET framework, using jQuery 1.4.2 client side.

When developing in Firefox version 3.6, every so often an one of the many ajax calls I make on the page will fire twice, the second will return successfully but will not trigger the success handler of the ajax call and the first never returns anything. So basically the data is all sent to the server and response is sent down but nothing happens with the response.

Here is an example of the call I am making. It happens to any of the ajax calls, so there is not one particular that is causing the problem:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:"{}",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(){
      alert('success');
    },
    error:function(){
      alert('error');
    },
    url:'/services.aspx/somemethod'
 });
```

})

From firebug, here are the headers of the first call which in firebug shows as never completely responding, meaning i see no response code and the loader gif in the firebug never goes away.

Note:In firebug it usually says Response Header but for the first call this space is blank

```
Server             ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727   
Content-Type      application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection           Close
```

**Request Headers**

```
Host              mydomain.com
User-Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) 
                  Gecko/20100401Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)   
Accept        application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding   gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive        115
Connection        keep-alive
Content-Type      application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
Referer       http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx
```

Here is the header from the second request which just appear to complete in firebug (i.e response is 200):

**Response Header**

```
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection  Close
```

**Request Headers**

```
Host        mydomain.com
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3)          
                Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept      text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive      115
Connection      keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer     http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx
```

To summarize my question, why are two requests being made and why are neither of them triggering a success or error handler in the ajax call.

I have seen this article about firefox 3.5+ and preflighted requests

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests

In the article is says if a "POST" is made with any other content type than 
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain" than the request is pre-flighted. If this is the case, this should happen to all of my calls.

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior with any other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried without the `dataType` option?

Comment: No I haven't, what is your reasoning?

Comment: Currently I am testing to see if it can be reproduced with Firebug off

Comment: Ok, in the amount of time that I have been testing, I should have run into the problem again. I am going to continue testing my application and if I still see no issues, I am going to post "firebug is the culprit" as the answer

Comment: My reasoning for suggesting trying without the `dataType` option is that you have evidence that certain `Content-type` headers will cause this behavior in Firefox 3.5+, and the `dataType` option is setting the `Content-type` header to one such value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer as much as a proposed temporary workaround. Make the call synchronous with `async:false` and see if things work again.

I've been tearing my hair out over a similar-sounding bug recently.

Comment: I need to do more testing before I want to put it up on S.O., but for anyone interested:


It happens with jQuery 1.3.2 and Firefox. One common factor seems to be that I am making one AJAX call, and the additional calls are all launched by the on-success method after that.

Only the first (parent) AJAX call and the final one of the child-calls appear to ever complete, although FireBug shows them all happening and the server gets them all. It's not a pure race condition, since stepping through it with a debugger still causes the problem. Making the child-calls synchronous "fixes" it.

Comment: The worst part of this problem is that it is difficult reproduce, it happens every hour or so, but even so I would not want any of these calls to be async as a solution.